# OpenEdge Progress 12.7 - can't insert data into table after adding SQL trigger

Tags: sql, jdbc, openedge, progress-db

I'm having tons of problems with adding and using SQL triggers with OE Progress 12.7 database.

I'm using **sports2020** database, user with DBA+Resources access.

I can add new rows into (for example) table **PUB.BillTo** without any problems, everything works as expected.

`INSERT INTO PUB.BillTo (CustNum) VALUES (<number>)`

But right after I add "before insert" trigger to the table (Column 2 is Integer), like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg1406 BEFORE INSERT ON PUB.BillTo
REFERENCING NEWROW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    NEWROW.setValue(2, 1990);
END
```

inserting more rows stops working, and JDBC driver just returns error:

`org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [HY000]: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver]Transliteration failed, reason: invalid UTF8 data     at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:133)    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:582)  at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$1(SQLQueryJob.java:491)  at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:501)    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:934)   at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3921)   at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:123)     at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:189)     at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)  at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:5101)  at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver]Transliteration failed, reason: invalid UTF8 data  at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.ddb9.b(Unknown Source)   at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.ddb9.a(Unknown Source)   at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.ddb8.b(Unknown Source)   at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.ddb8.a(Unknown Source)   at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.client.dde.a(Unknown Source)     at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.client.dde.af(Unknown Source)    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.client.dde.aa(Unknown Source)    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.client.dde.c(Unknown Source)     at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.client.dde._(Unknown Source)     at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.ddf.b(Unknown Source)    at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.ddek.w(Unknown Source)   at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.ddek.s(Unknown Source)   at com.ddtek.jdbc.openedgebase.ddek.execute(Unknown Source)     at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:330)     at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:131)    ... 11 more`

Googling didn't help at all, since every page expects me to be reading data, but I'm actually adding them. Also, I'm not adding text, just numbers.

I tried same steps in **DBeaver 23.1.2**, **SQLEXP** (included in OE Progress) and **OE Studio**. Same results.

I also can't get to work more complex trigger logic with imports from Java, etc. But honestly, right now I would be happy just with this.

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks!

P.S.: Using another database system isn't an option, unfortunately.